# Hibernate ManyToMany save relation both sides

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a relation ManyToMany between a User and a Role (members is the relational table). I can save the relation from the role to user but not the user to role.

User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

Role.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "members", catalog = "blackant_db", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =     "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

When I merge a set of users into a role, hibernate save the relation, otherwise hibernate only update the object user. E.g:

RoleService

```
Role role = roleService.findById(1);
Set<User> currentUsers = role.getUsers();
roleDAO.clear();
currentUsers.addAll(users);
role.setUsers(currentUsers);
roleDAO.merge(role);
//This works, save the user relationship into table members
```

UserService

```
User user = userService.findById(1);
Set<Role> currentRoles = user.getRoles();
userDAO.clear();
currentRoles.addAll(roles);
user.setUsers(currentUsers);
userDAO.merge(user);
//This doesn't work, only save the user
```

How can I save the set of users/roles in both sides?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

have u try to add cascade statement in User too?

/**
 * (Optional) The operations that must be cascaded to the target
 * of the association.
 *
 *

When the target collection is a {@link java.util.Map
 * java.util.Map}, the `cascade` element applies to the
 * map value.
 *
 *

Defaults to no operations being cascaded.
 */
CascadeType[] cascade() default {};